# An 'all encompassing' formal definition of 'graph'

Tags: graph-theory

I've not been able to find a formal definition of ***graph*** that's  *all encompassing*.

By  *all encompassing*,  I mean a formal definition of ***graph*** that's so general, that each of the various types of graph one usually encounters in the literature (for example: directed graphs, multigraphs, graphs with loops, etc.) is just a special case of that general definition.

Does anyone know of such an  *all encompassing*  formal definition of ***graph***?

If not, if someone has come across (or thought of) a formal definition of ***graph*** that's almost  *all encompassing*,  I would be very interested to hear of it.

I feel that many of us with an interest in graph theory would consider an  *all encompassing*  (or very generalized)  formal definition of ***graph*** to be potentially useful.

I hope someone can provide us with such a definition!

Comment: While we're at it, could someone please come up with an all encompassing definition of "number"?

Comment: Will it include infinite graphs?  Voltage graphs?  Why do you want this?  You say it would be "potentially useful" but I don't see how.

Comment: Starting with a more general definition of something often results in theorems/findings that have a greater applicability/utility.  Category theory illustrates this principle extremely well.  Also, just look at the myriad of definitions of 'graph' that, despite being plausible/self-consistent, are very often incompatible with one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here goes:

A graph is a triple $(V,E,f)$ where $V$ is a set (the vertices of the graph),
$E$ is a set (the edges of the graph), and $f \colon E \to V^{<\omega}$ is a function assigning to each edge its set of vertices, where $V^{<\omega}$ means the set of all tuples (finite sequences) from $V$.

This is general enough to include hypergraphs, directed graphs, and multigraphs. Graphs with various labelings or colorings (e.g. voltage graphs) just add some more functions from $V$ or $E$ to some set.

In the case of any graph which isn't a hypergraph, $f$ will map into $V \times V \subset V^{<\omega}$. For a non-directed graph, the order of the entries in the ordered pair $f(e)$ for each edge $e$ will be ignored. For a simple graph, $f$ is required to be injective and to avoid the subset $\Delta V = \{ (v,v) \mid v \in V \} \subset V \times V$.

---

To be able to distinguish undirected edges from directed edges without some prior knowledge of how the graph is to be interpreted, we change the definition so that $f: E \to V^{<\omega} \cup 2^V$ is a function into the set of all tuples from $V$ and all subsets of $V$. Edges which map to tuples are directed; edges which map to subsets are not directed.

So: an undirected loop $e$ maps to a singleton set $\{v\}$; a directed loop maps to the ordered pair $(v, v)$; a "semi-edge" maps to the 1-tuple $(v)$.

Comment: Impressive! (Thanks!)  Just an observation, though ... Under this definition, it's possible for one to be given a (V, E, f) triple, and not know from that triple whether the graph it represents is directed, undirected or mixed.  Can you offer a definition for which one is always able to conclude from an instantiation of it, which edges are directed and which edges aren't?

Comment: @memexor: See my edit.

Comment: Excellent!  Whilst I know that one can keep generalizing the definition of 'graph' ad infinitum (for example, edges being allowed to connect vertices and/or edges with other vertices and/or edges), I feel that your definition strikes just the right balance of generality for me (it encompasses all of the main 'graph' variants that I've come across).  Big thanks, for helping out!